# Load data from one oracle db to another oracle db best practices/methods

Tags: database, oracle, design-patterns, architecture

I wanted to do onetime load from one source Oracle db to destination oracle db.
it can't done direct load /unload or import/export of data as it as different tables structures columns at source and destination. so it requires good transformation,
My plan is to get the data as in XML format from the source DB and process the XML to destination DB.
and also Data volume would be more ( 1 to 20+ million records or more in some tables) and the databases involved are : Oracle (source) and Oracle (destination),
Please provide some best practices or best way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that I understand why you can't do a direct load.

If you create a database link on the destination database that points to the source database, you can then put your ETL logic into SQL statements that `SELECT` from the source database and `INSERT` into the destination database.  That avoids the need to write the data to a flat file, to read that flat file, to parse the XML, etc. which is going to be slow and require a decent amount of coding.  That way, you can focus on the ETL logic and you can migrate the data as efficiently as possible.

You can write SQL (or PL/SQL) that loads directly from the old table structure on the old database to the new table structure on the new database.

```
INSERT INTO new_table( <<list of columns>> )
  SELECT a.col1, a.col2, ... , b.colN, b.colN+1
    FROM old_table_1@link_to_source a,
         old_table_2@link_to_source b
   WHERE <<some join condition>>
```

Comment: Thanks, why I can't do a direct load i don't want the source table and columns created, i have different table structures at destination they are not same as source tables and columns.
Since its one time data-load, in this case is it worth to use ETL? I know SQL, PL/SQL. I’m new to ETL, please suggest.

Comment: @balu - I'm still not sure that I understand what the problem is.  You can implement the ETL (which just stands for Extract Transform Load) logic in SQL and/or PL/SQL.  I posted an example of doing a direct load from two tables in the source system to a single table in the destination system.  There is no need to create the source tables in the destination database.